# When a capacitor discharges in a simple RC circuit, is it treated as an active component?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, capacitance, electronics

While deriving expression for the voltage across capacitor in a discharging RC circuit, I stumbled across whether I should treat the capacitor as an active or a passive component(To properly apply the loop rule).
Any help will be appreciated....

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/science/electrical-engineering/ee-circuit-analysis-topic/circuit-elements/a/ee-sign-convention

Answer (score 1):

The *constitutive relationship* of an ideal capacitor is

$$i = C\frac{\mathrm{d} v}{\mathrm{d} t}$$

when voltage and current directions associated to the capacitor are chosen according to the *passive* sign convention, regardless of whether the capacitor is charging or discharging. If, instead, you chose the active sign convention, the constitutive relationship would be

$$i = -C\frac{\mathrm{d} v}{\mathrm{d} t}.$$

That is, a constitutive relationship does not depend on the actual current flow, but only on the assigned associated directions, which can be arbitrary. Thus, it doesn't matter whether you treat the capacitor as a passive or active component, but you have to use the constitutive relationship consistent with the chosen current and voltage directions.