# Calculating the differential equation associated with an LC circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, inductance

[image]

Looking at the above diagram I know that the current associated with a capacitor is given by:

$$
I_c = C \frac{d^2 \phi} {{dt}^2}
$$

and the inductor current is given by:

$$
I_l = \frac{\phi} {L} 
$$

In a series circuit I expected the current that goes through the inductor to be the same as the current that goes through the capacitor (i.e. the current to travel from the bottom plate of the capacitor, through the inductor and then reach the top capacitor plate) so:

$$
C \frac{d^2 \phi} {{dt}^2} = \frac{\phi} {L} 
$$

However this is incorrect compared to the actual LC circuit differential equation given by:

$$
C \frac{d^2 \phi} {{dt}^2} + \frac{\phi} {L} = 0
$$

What am I misunderstanding?

Thanks

Comment: What's $\phi$ in your equation?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano flux

Answer (score 2):

The *constitutive equations* of electrical elements are always written with respect to certain associated directions of voltage and current or of other pairs of conjugate quantities. If one changes the associated directions, one should change the constitutive equations (see also [this post of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/588764/111969)).

For a capacitor in which current and voltage directions are chosen according to the *passive sign convention*, the constitutive relationship is

$$i = C\frac{\mathrm{d} v}{\mathrm{d} t}.$$

In the passive sign convention, the current $i$ enters where the voltage polarity is conventionally positive, as you drew in the attached schematic.

With respect to the current $i$ and the voltage $v$, though, the constitutive equation for the inductor is

$$v = -L\frac{\mathrm{d} i}{\mathrm{d} t}.$$

If we now define the flux linkage $\phi$ as the integral of $v$ (and not $-v$), the two above equations become

$$i = C\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 \phi}{\mathrm{d} t^2}$$

and

$$\phi = -Li$$

Substituting $i$ from the second equation into the first yields

$$C\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 \phi}{\mathrm{d} t^2}+\frac{\phi}{L}=0.$$

Put another way, if you want to stick to the passive sign convention for both elements, then you have to take into account that $I_L = -i$.

Comment: Is there a more intuitive explanation of this? Physically what does it mean for the current of an inductor to be negative?

Comment: @NahPlsMan That's and entirely different question. A negative current is just that the  (positive) charges move in the opposite direction with respect to the direction one chooses as reference. Recall that the current is a scalar quantity equal to the time derivative of the charge $q$ transferred through a _directed_ surface. Reversing the surface direction, that is, the reference direction, changes the current sign. Don't search for a more intuitive explanation, learn the basics properly.

Comment: @NahPlsMan For instance, when you connect an ammeter to a circuit, the reference direction for the current measured by the ammeter is given by the red and black terminals: the current read by the ammeter is positive when it flows from the red to the black terminal. To measure the current $i$ in your circuit you would have to connect the red terminal toward the inductor and the black toward the capacitor, breaking the circuit in the upper branch. If you exchange the terminals, you measure the current $-i$.

Answer (score 1):

A LC circuit is an harmonic oscillator. Its differential equation must be the same of its mechanical equivalent:

$F = -kx \implies \frac{dp}{dt} = -kx$

Following the [equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical%E2%80%93electrical_analogies):
$F \rightarrow V$
$k \rightarrow \frac{1}{C}$
$x \rightarrow Q$
$v \rightarrow I$
$m \rightarrow L$
$p = mv \rightarrow \phi = LI$

$$\frac{d\phi}{dt} = -\frac{1}{C}Q$$

Taking the derivative with respect to time, and placing all terms at the same side:

$$\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2} + \frac{1}{C}I = 0$$

Subtituting $I = \frac{\phi}{L}$ and multiplying both sides by $C$:

$$C\frac{d^2\phi}{dt^2} + \frac{1}{L}\phi = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Very good answer above by Massimo, and direct.  I'm just adding my answer FYI which uses Laplace transform methods taught to electrical engineers - basically we convert the time-domain circuit (differential equations) to the frequency domain (simple algebraic equations), solve it, and then transform it back to the time-domain.  Once you have $i(t)$ and/or $v(t)$ you can find your differential equation easily from the fundamental equations of the inductor and capacitor.

Below is your circuit in the time-domain and the fundamental equations governing it,
[image]

Now, below is your circuit Laplace transformed to the frequency domain. The inductor value, $L$, is replaced with its Laplace operational impedance, $sL$.  Just below it you see a DC voltage source that is proportional to the inductance times the initial current, $i(0)$.  The capacitor value, $C$, is replaced with its Laplace operation impedance, $\frac{1}{sC}$.  Just below it you see a DC voltage source that is proportional to the initial voltage, $V(0)$, divided by $s$.

[image]

Once the circuit is transformed, you simply use all the "normal" rules for solving simple DC circuits that are available ([KVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), [source transformations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Theory/Source_Transformations) etc.) to solve for whatever quantities you want ($i(t), v(t)$ etc.).  Then you transform your solution back to the time-domain.

Solving your circuit for $i(t)$,

$$i(t)=\frac{Li(0)-\frac{V(0)}{s}}{sL+\frac{1}{sC}}$$

Which simplifies to,

$$i(t)=\frac{i(0)s}{s^2+\frac{1}{LC}}\text{ }-\text{ }\frac{\frac{V(0)}{L}}{s^2+\frac{1}{LC}}  $$

These terms are easily inverse Laplace transformed back to the time domain using [tables of transform pairs](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/LaplaceZTable/Common%20Laplace%20Transform%20Pairs.pdf).

So, using the 10th & 11th pairs in the table I link to above, we get:

$$i(t) = i(0)cos(\omega_0 t)\text{ }-\text{ }\frac{V(0)\omega_0}{Z_0}sin(\omega_0 t)  $$

where the natural or resonant frequency $\omega_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}$ and the characteristic impedance $Z_0=\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}$.

If you want to combine the sinusoids (since they are at same frequency) to further simplify you can.  You can do this with simple [phasor math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor#:%7E:text=In%20physics%20and%20engineering%2C%20a,%CE%B8) or other [handy formula](https://dspguru.com/files/Sum_of_Two_Sinusoids.pdf) such as the following,

$$K_1cos(\omega_0 t)+K_2sin(\omega_0 t)=\sqrt{K_1^2+K_2^2}\text{  }cos\left[\omega_0 t-tan^{-1}\frac{K_2}{K_1}\right]   $$

You can see from our solved equation for $i(t)$ that the circuit when closed will just oscillate (ring) at the resonant frequency $\omega_0$.

Finally, once you have solved for the current or voltage you can find charge easily too,

$$q(t) = Cv(t)$$

$$q(t) = \int{i(t)}$$

Here are the fundamental element models in Laplace,

[image]

Finally, slide 28 of [this nice writeup](https://www.ius.edu.ba/sites/default/files/u772/ee202laplacetransform.pdf) shows a simple example you can work through.